# Image size warnings and what cropping field means in django-image-cropping

Tags: django, image-processing, django-views, jcrop

I'm trying to use django-image-cropping app on my website. I've set it up with size warnings on. Build in warnings are not good enough for me - as I understand if I try use size smaller than defined frame color in cutting tool is changing but nothing more. I'd like to check sizes in view but cleaned_data contains only cropping value which is string with 4 numbers in it. Does anybody know what those 4 numbers describe? Or maybe there is another way to prevent cropping not allowed sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case someone is as shortsighted as me, after some time of analyzing I've came up with answer:

value of cropping field is codded like this:

'cropping': "num1, num2, num3, num4" where:

num1 - number of pixels by which jcrop-vline is shifted from the left edge

num2 - number of pixels by which jcrop-hline is shifted from the top edge

num3 - number of pixels by which jcrop-vline-right is shifted from the left edge

num4 - number of pixels by which jcrop-hline-bottom is shifted from the top edge